# My screen does not match my tv size in my Linux desktop

Tags: linux, drivers, linux-mint, tv, dell-precision

I've got a Dell Desktop connected to a TV. Borders doesn't work well in the desktop. Check the photos:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**TV**: LG 55UM7100PB (https://www.lg.com/sg/tvs/lg-55UH615T-uhdtv)

**DESKTOP**: DELL Precision T7400 (https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/precision-t7400/docs) connected via HDMI. Dell has the latest Linux Mint distribution just installed with Cinnamon.

I had a Windows 10 installed too with the very same problem... but as this DELL is pretty old Windows didn't have drivers for graphics card so it was running over a "basic microsoft driver"

*Everything* has all latest drivers.

I tested other hardware. I have a PlayStation 4 that works ok with the tv. Also connected my laptop (Windows 10) to the tv with no problem.

**My questions are**:

1. Is this a TV problem or a Linux problem?
2. Could it be fixed on Linux Mint? How?
3. If I reinstall with Linux Mint MATE or xfce will it got fixed?
4. Is there another linux distro that could work better?

Comment: 1. Linux
2. Yes
3. No
4. Probably
show the output of the `xrandr` command when the TV is connected. The screen is cool !!!

Comment: add custom resolution (f.e.3840 x 2160) in `xrandr` and create script https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=disable+overscan+linux

Comment: more - https://medium.com/@AbhiXpert/add-change-the-custom-resolution-of-your-display-using-xrandr-on-ubuntu-18-04-in-a-minute-338caec6e29

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/978871/ubuntu-and-changing-resolution-to-4k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem of the PC.

For historical reasons, TVs overscan the signal by default and computer monitors don't. In any case a TV is not a good computer monitor, and vice versa.

Change the image aspect ratio settings from the TV menus to fit the picture to screen so there is no overscan.

Based on the manual of the 55UM7100PB, the setting is called "Just Scan".

LGs seem to have that separate from the actual aspect ratio setting. Normally other TVs include this as one of the options in the aspect ratio setting.

Comment: You might even get lucky & just find a "PC" setting on the TV which will include disabling overscan, or a dedicated overscan control.

Comment: I remember Overscan/Underscan being affected by the video card and driver in use, combined with the X11 config, but not in ways that were really predictable/controllable. granted that was with Ubunutu 7.04 and an analog TV, so it has to be easier to address these days.

Comment: You nailed it. I activated Just Scan and worked :-)